# Can threads switch CPUs?

Tags: python, multithreading, jython, cpu-usage, multicore

At my workplace there is a shared powerful 24-core server on which we run our jobs. To utilize full power of the multi-core CPU I wrote a multi-threaded version of a long-running program such that 24 threads are run on each core simultaneously (via `threading` library in `Jython`).

The program runs speedily if there are no other jobs running. However, I was running a big job simultaneously on one core and as a result the thread running on that particular core took long amount of time, slowing down the entire program (as threads needed to join the data at the end). However the threads on other CPUs had long finished execution - so I basically had 23 cores idle and 1 core running the thread and the heavy job, or at least this is what my diagnosis is. This was further confirmed by looking at output of `time` command, sys time was very low compared to user time (which means there was lot of waiting).

Does operating system (`Linux` in this case) not switch jobs to different CPUs if one CPU is loaded while others are idle? If not, can I do that in my program (in `Jython`). It should not be difficult to query different CPU loads once in a while and then switch to one that is relatively free.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a programming question

Comment: @user2618501: It is, because I want to know if it is possible to do CPU switching in `Python`, particularly `Jython`.

Comment: Is your process CPU-bound or IO-bound? And, generally, how much faster does the 24-thread version go than the one-thread version?

Comment: @Rob: The process has a balanced usage of CPU and IO waiting. Also, the speed gains in `Python` are not translated as one would expect based on number of cores because of `GIL` related issues (or lack of it in `Jython` which introduces certain overload). Nevertheless I was able to achieve 3x performance on the 24-core machine.

Comment: Jython has no GIL. It uses the threading capabilities of the JVM. See http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/Concurrency.html#no-global-interpreter-lock

Comment: I would suggest using an OS-specific version of processor affinity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity  Normally the OS automatically determines the assignment of threads to CPUs but there are OS-specific ways of binding a thread to a CPU of your choice.

Comment: Threads move among cpus and shouldn't get stuck like this unless a processor affinity has been set. Run `ps <pid> -L -o tid,psr,pcpu` for the pid of your python program and the cpu-hog. That will give you snapshots of where the threads are running for a better picture of whats going on.

Comment: It would make more sense not to rely on all the cores being available to you. Don't try to use all available cores: leave a few for other tasks.

Comment: @EJP: The problem is, since it's a shared machine, I would never know how many cores are being used. Ideally if out of 24 cores, n are being in use, I would like to allocate 1 out of remaining (24-n) for the long running single threaded task and then some of (24-n-1) for the parallel task leaving a few free for potential incoming jobs.

Answer (score 2):

Source http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-scheduler/:

> To maintain a balanced workload across CPUs, work can be
>   redistributed, taking work from an overloaded CPU and giving it to an
>   underloaded one. The Linux 2.6 scheduler provides this functionality
>   by using load balancing. Every 200ms, a processor checks to see
>   whether the CPU loads are unbalanced; if they are, the processor
>   performs a cross-CPU balancing of tasks.
>
> A negative aspect of this process is that the new CPU's cache is cold
>   for a migrated task (needing to pull its data into the cache).

Looks like Linux has been balancing threads across cores for a while now.

However, assuming Linux load balances instantly (which it doesn't), your problem still reduces to one where you have 23 cores and 24 tasks.  In the worst case (where all tasks take equally long), this takes twice as long as having only 23 tasks because, if they all take equally long to complete, then the last task still has to wait for another task to run to completion before there is a free core.

If the wall-clock time of the program suffers by a slowdown of around 2x, this is probably the issue.

If it is drastically worse than 2x, then you may be on an older version of the Linux scheduler.